# Stripe integration and Price Object creation in Vue CLI application with vue-stripe-checkout

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I try to integrate **Stripe** in my **Vue CLI** application.
To do this, I decided to use the **[vue-stripe-checkout package](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout)**.

I specify that **all the data necessary for the smooth running of the payment are stored in my application during a form completion**

At first, everything went well, **I followed the example of the demo** offered by the package and **I browsed the documentation**. It's from there that I'm stuck.

The package requires entering different data like items. The problem is that **"items" requires a sku**, but i don't have it. I therefore preferred to inform **"lineItems"** but here too, I have to inform a **Price Object** that I don't have...

I found how to create a Price Object [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create), but I don't know how and when to do that in my application.

Here is my code

```html
<template>
    <stripe-checkout
    ref="checkoutRef"
    :pk="publishableKey"
    :lineItems="lineItems"
    :successUrl="successUrl"
    :cancelUrl="cancelUrl"
    >
        <template slot="checkout-button">
            <button @click="checkout">Payment</button>
        </template>
    </stripe-checkout>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
    import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe-checkout';

    export default {
        components: {
            StripeCheckout
        },
        data() {
            return {
                loading: false,
                publishableKey: 'pk_test', 
                // redirectToCheckout
                lineItems: [
                    {
                        price: '', // Price Object
                        quantity: 1,
                    }
                ],
                mode: 'payment',
                customerEmail: null, // Assigned in created lifecycle hook
                successUrl: 'https://success_url.com',
                cancelUrl: 'https://cancel_url.com',
            };
        },
        methods: {
            checkout() {
                this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: SKU is an older, deprecated API, but you can still find the docs via the direct link here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/skus

Comment: Thank you but I know the documentation and I don't want to use items with SKU but lineItems with Price Object.

Comment: You'd need to use a different tool than vue-stripe-checkout then, as that is the legacy version of Checkout that requires SKU's.

Comment: However, as I said in my first post, it is possible to use vue-stripe-checkout with Price Object if we use lineItems instead of items, as mentioned here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout

Answer (score 0):

You create a product from your Stripe Dashboard and get its price id. You enter the price id in the price field then its ready to go!